# The physics behind Hohmann Transfer Orbits

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

I was recently reading about Hohmann transfer orbits from the MIT courseware 
 on orbital transfer ([source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec17.pdf)).

I have two questions.

How did they arrive at the equations for $v_{\pi}$ and $v_{\alpha}$?

They have taken the potential at a radial distance of $r_1+r_2$ when the particle to be transferred never crosses $r_2$

The time taken for the transfer is ${\displaystyle t_{\text{H}}={\frac {1}{2}}{\sqrt {\frac {4\pi ^{2}a_{\text{H}}^{3}}{\mu }}}=\pi {\sqrt {\frac {(r_{1}+r_{2})^{3}}{8\mu }}}}$

How have they arrived at this equation?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: I constructed this answer from the text you provided and the very helpful [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit) article.

The Hohmann transfer orbit is used to transfer an object orbiting around a body from one circular orbit to another via an elliptical orbit. The assumption is that there are no other gravitational forces present and the mass of the object is much smaller than the mass of the body being orbited ($m\ll M$). This image is taken from the source you provided:

[image]

As you can see, the transfer orbit is achieved via two impulses (that we assume to be instantaneous). One at the perigee, and another at the apogee of the ellipse. We can also see that since the longest axis of the ellipse is $r_1+r_2$, the semi-major axis of the ellipse is $a=\frac{r_1+r_2}{2}$. We will now do some basic celestial mechanics.

When an object orbits another, we can add its gravitational potential energy and its kinetic energy to get the total energy of the orbit,

$$E=K+U=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{GMm}{r}$$

We will use the notation $\mu=GM$, known as the gravitational parameter. The [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation#Derivation_for_elliptic_orbits_(0_%E2%89%A4_eccentricity_%3C_1)) is a little involved but the upshot is that this total energy is equal to half the potential at the semi-major axis of the orbit,

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{\mu m}{r}=-\frac{\mu m}{2a}$$

This comes from conservation of angular momentum: $mv_\pi r_\pi=mv_\alpha r_\alpha$. If the velocities at the perigee ($\pi$) and apogee ($\alpha$) are related in this way, and the total energy of the orbit is to remain the same at both these points, we find that it must equal $-\frac{\mu m}{2a}$.

Solving the above expression gives us the velocity of an object in an elliptical orbit a distance $r$ from a body as,

$$v^2=\mu\bigg(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\bigg)$$

The expression for $v_\pi$ and $v_\alpha$ comes from setting $r=r_1$ and $r=r_2$ respectively in this equation, corresponding to the radius of the orbit you want to leave (perigee) and the one you want to enter (apogee). Note we also substitute the expression for the semi-major axis $a$ in.

Since we assumed instantaneous thrusts, we can find our delta-v's by simply taking a difference between the perigee/apogee speeds and the orbital speeds at those circular orbits. Equating centripetal and gravitational force gives the orbital speed as,

$$\frac{mv^2}{r}=\frac{\mu m}{r^2}\Rightarrow v=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r}}$$

The delta-v's are then,

$$\Delta v_\pi=v_\pi-v_{r_1}=\sqrt{\mu\bigg(\frac{2}{r_1}-\frac{2}{r_1+r_2}\bigg)}-\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r_1}}= \\ \sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r_1}}\Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{2r_2}{r_1+r_2}}-1\Bigg)$$

By symmetry, for the apogee,

$$\Delta v_\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{r_2}}\Bigg(\sqrt{\frac{2r_1}{r_1+r_2}}-1\Bigg)$$

In terms of the time taken for the orbit, we can use Kepler's Third Law, which states the square of the period of an elliptical orbit is proportional to the cube of its semi-major axis,

$$T^2=\frac{4\pi^2a^3}{\mu}$$

We simply note that the object only traverses half the ellipse in the Hohmann transfer orbit so it will take half the period of this orbit,

$$t_H=\frac{1}{2}T=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2a_H^3}{\mu}}$$

Comment: thanks a lot Archie.